# This should have been Improve Edit

Tags: support, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

[Linky](//stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14083462)

One user chose <kbd>Reject and Edit</kbd>—and then proceeded to do *exactly* what my own edit did. This is what <kbd>Improve Edit</kbd> is for.

Looking over their review history, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14083639) (debatable) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13974684) should have also been <kbd>Improve Edit</kbd>.

I'm not *particulary* annoyed—it's just one edit, after all—but how can I send them a gentle reminder of how these should have been reviewed?

Comment: Well, discussing about editing turds may become _stinky_

Comment: @yellowantphil I don't usually edit those out; they usually get approved anyway.

Comment: @StephenLeppik That's because there are a huge amount of robo reviewers that click approve without reading. If you're making an edit and getting it into a queue, you should fix *everything*, or *nothing*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is nothing seriously wrong with this "Reject and edit".

Edit going through review process is expected to take care of all (at least all obvious) issues in the post. The change updated code formatting to different style and did not remove "thank you" notes. So "reject and edit" is proper choice to gently remind editor that there are more issues with the post. Simple reject would be fine too as there were no serious problems with formatting to start with.

Original post had code formatted reasonably fine - extra column of spaces did not had real impact on readability (or completeness) of the post. Updating one spacing style to another is not good edit, especially if it needs to be reviewed.

If incomplete edits are being usually approved it simply means that reviewers don't pay enough attention to the posts being edited... and not that partial edits are ok.

---

On the last question "how can I send them a gentle reminder" - you can @-comment any editor in the history of the post even if autocomplete does not add them (unlike people who actually commented on the post).

Comment: Regarding sending them a reminder... you might want to consider that carefully. The user in this case has been on the site for 5 *years*; you've been on the site for 5 *months*. Not saying that people who have been on the site for that long can't make mistakes, but you may want to consider your relative experience levels when drafting the reminder...