# Why was my edit rejected and improved?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

I'm a little confused as to why my edit was rejected and improved. Here is my edit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14182366

First of all, I will explain to you what my edit consisted of:

1. I removed 'thanks' from the bottom of the post.
2. I removed the phrase 'My question is:' as I felt this wasn't needed and it would be better to get straight to the question.

However it seems like a user disagreed with my edit and "improved" it by removing the removal of the phrase 'My question is:' in my edit.

Is this worth rejecting an edit? From my opinion, when you "reject" an edit, you disagree with it, which isn't the case here as they kept in the removal of 'thanks' from my edit - wouldn't it have been a better choice to approve and edit?

Comment: Yep, you are right, that should have been at the very least approved, or improved and edited

Comment: You would have to ask the user, I'll however bet he'd say "absolutely!"  Such are the risks of having your edits reviewed.  It isn't going to be any different once you got enough rep to no longer need review, somebody can still edit your edit.  And will.  The basic idea of giving you the option of editing before you have enough rep is to help you get used to stuff like this.

Comment: _From my opinion, when you "reject" an edit, you disagree with it_ I would also reject an edit that didn't deal with most problems in a post. Just removing thanks or fixing one thing would get rejected if there were spelling mistakes or other glaringly obvious errors. But if 5/6 mistakes were fixed, I'd improve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This should have been Improve Edit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336856/this-should-have-been-improve-edit)

Comment: IIRC, that is an exploit for one shot apply, without waiting another approval.

Comment: I think we should remove "First of all, I will explain to you what my edit consisted of". This is too wordy and doesn't get to the point. It should read "My edit consisted of". <-- Everyone here has irrelevant words in their posts/answers.

Answer (score 7):

IMHO, that was a reasonable edit and should not have been rejected. Unfortunately, we all make mistakes. This happens from time to time and should not discourage you from editing. At least I'm happy somebody is reviewing without blindly robo-approving all non-audit reviews.

Comment: robo-rejecting all non-audits? :p

Comment: Hehe :) that [doesn't seem the case](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4211135/brianpck?tab=activity&sort=reviews), though.

Answer (score 4):

I've now edited the question in [better shape yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060361/accessing-variables-inside-embedded-swf).

- moved the question to the top to help readability
- punctuated
- separated different concerns in three steps

Which, as [Servy rightly comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337436/why-was-my-edit-rejected-and-improved/337438?noredirect=1#comment410421_337437), makes me wonder if really then that edit should have been approved. Indeed, the state in which the reviewer left the question was not optimal, yet the proposed edit also did not address all problems.

I now believe the proper action would have been to either reject or approve (that part is left for reviewer discretion) **and** edit the question in proper shape.

Comment: The edit rejection would be merited, when you consider all of the things the suggested edit missed, as seen in later edits.

Comment: hmmm... interesting plot twist indeed

Comment: You, and the prior editors, all did not add code formatting to the variable that is used in the text `bgURL`. Your removal of "where I'm" should have put some other connector between the phrases (e.g. "which loads"). You did not capitalize the second "swf" to SWF, or indicated it as `.swf` or *.swf*. "Probably through the bgURL?" was reasonable as a parenthetical, but is a fragment that should be expanded once you have pulled it out to stand alone. Removal of the "but I can't figure out how" reduces the amount of thought that it is implied the OP has put into the problem.

Comment: @Makyen adding code formating on the text is a slippery slope... where do you stop?

Comment: @Braiam, I'm not sure what you are trying to ask. Do you have an example where you would *not* use code formatting for code that is within the text? My default answer would be: If it is code, it should be in code formatting to indicate that it is code. This is for multiple reasons, including both to highlight where the text is talking about code and to distinguish between when the text is using words which could be used both as code and as English text.  For instance, while you are talking about a `while` loop.

Comment: @Makyen here we go. What qualifies as code? Keywords? Packages names? Companies? If it's clear from the context that it has special meaning, there's no need to use formatting. Reserve formatting for when it's *needed*, for cases where even without it it will be understood, formatting can be counterproductive.

Comment: @Servy not sure if your comment was a self fulfilling prophecy or a downright lucid understanding ;)

Comment: @Makyen: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14216704) is an example edit from someone who just `loves` to "highlight important text" using `code` ticks.

Comment: @RadLexus, That is a decent example of inappropriate use of code formatting for things that are not code; none of the added code formatting is appropriate. I would rejected that edit & the subsequent edit. The fact that some people erroneously use code formatting for things that are not code does not reflect on my assertion that things that *are code* should be in code format. Code formatting is also appropriate for things like error messages and where a `<pre>` and/or a monospaced font are beneficial/needed. Code formatting should **not** be used for general emphasis of text.

Answer (score -3):

I can't speak for the person who rejected the edit, but I would reject this as "no improvement whatsoever" as I don't see how minor pedantic edits to a question asked over five years ago with almost no views – much less votes – adds anything to the site.

The same applies to the subsequent edits after this meta question was asked. The original question was perfectly clear, and [bikeshedding](https://shed.bike/) it into something *you* would prefer is not why there are edit privileges; they're there to improve questions, not to enforce your favo[u]rite spelling, word choice, sentence order, etc.

Answer (score -9):

Actually when I'm reading a question I like the OP to draw my attention to their main question by saying "This is my question". It is then very clear what I'm meant to be answering and what content I'm meant to put emphasis on.

I would argue the edit took away from the clarity in this case.

Comment: "My question is the following sentence that ends with a question mark."